# How can I unescape a string from python using javascript

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to work on passing a url from my backend to my frontend and it has some escaping going on such that by the time the string gets to the frontend it looks something like `&#34www.test.com&#34`.

Is there a way I can unescape this string or is my best solution here to just manually replace substrings of `&#34` with quotes?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: your best solution is to find function which incorrectly escapes quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'&#34www.test.com&#34'.replace(/&#34/g,'')
```

output:

```
 "www.test.com"
```